# Runtime Permission не работает

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Насколько я знаю на android 6+ опасные разрешения должны запрашиваться во время исполнения программы. Я работаю с камерой - делаю фото и сохраняю его в папке. Позже вывожу это фото с папки в imageView. Понятное дело что мне надо вывести запрос на чтение,  но как бы я не пробовал, запрос не показывается и приходится давать все разрешения в ручную в настройках. Как и что исправить?

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        editText.setText("");

        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(_path);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) { //Если версия андроид больше 23 (6.0)
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, Math.round(width), Math.round(width * bitmap.getHeight() / bitmap.getWidth()), true);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(scaledBitmap);
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQ_CODE_READ_WRITE_EXTERNAL_DATA);
            }
        } 
        else {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
...
```

Comment: у вас запрос на чтение и запись на внешний накопитель прописан в манифесте?

Comment: Так Вы пытаетесь сначала прочитать картинку из файла (`BitmapFactory.decodeFile(_path)`), а только потом запросить разрешение на чтение. Надо наоборот и лучше перед вызовом камеры - смысл делать снимок если неизвестно сможем ли мы его забрать. В общем рецепт такой: запрашиваем разом разрешения на камеру и чтение/запись файлов, а когда всё получено спокойно вызываем камеру получаем и работаем со снимком.

Comment: В манифесте прописаны эти разрешения <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: Что касается камеры, то она работает как надо и без запросов, насколько я понимаю для работы системной камеры они не нужны